# Raster to vector, matching another vector in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, vector

I have taken a pdf of a map and managed to import it into my map using the QGIS geolocator. Now I want to convert the resulting raster layer to a set of polygons that match up with the existing vector layers. When I polygonize the raster layer, it's a mess.

Can someone get me started in the right direction?

Map

[image]

Map with raster (w/ transparency)

[image]

Map with polygonized raster

[image]

Or is it easier to use the raster overlay to note by hand which of the small areas fall within the the respective raster's areas?